# workers can't connect to master in spark standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

i installed apache spark 1.6 on 2 machines ubuntu (ip 192.168.217.136 hostname= worker-virtual-machine ) is the matser and (ip= 192.168.217.139 hostname =slave) is worker 
i configured ssh and configured folders slaves and spark-env.sh 
the cofiguration of slaves is

192.168.217.139
and for the spark-env.sh folder

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.217.136

export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1

export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=800m

export SPARK_WORKER_IN

STANCES=2
```

when i start the cluster by ./sbin/start-all.sh and enter the web GUI i found just 1 worker with ipadress of master connected  so the worker with 192.168.217.139 ipadress dosn't connect to the master [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GIAe.png)

i tried to start master by `./start-master.sh` and start  worker from worker machine by 
`./start-slaves.sh spark://192.168.217.136:7077`
and when enter jps command it show me worker created in terminal but when i move to the terminal of master and do jps it show me just master and the GUI doesn't show anything when i return to worker machine and do jps i don't find the worker

where is the problem ???

---

when i start worker manualy from its machine i have this message error in logs

[image]

Comment: could you paste the logs from the master?

Answer (score -1):

Reading [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html), you can see that the args for `./start-slave.sh` takes the `master IP address` as the first argument. This means you run ./start-slave.sh on the slave machine and point it to the master machine. It looks like you're doing the opposite: running on the master and pointing to the slave.

Comment: in the worker machin which has ip 192.168.217.139 i enter the command ./start-slave.sh spark://worker-virtual-machine:7077 and  ./start-slave.sh spark://192.168.217.136:7077 bu nothing happend !!!